# How can I connect Vue.js Frontend with Node.js, express and mongoDB Backend, like a MEVN stack?

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, frontend, backend

I've already built some websites using Node.js, express, and mongoDB, but using EJS. Now I'm learning Vue.js, and I'm loving it, but I still couldn't integrate it in this backend. Someone has a guide that I can follow, especially for beginners to intermediate?

Comment: It depends on what `integration` means here. You can make HTTP requests from Vue frontend to your backend using `axios` or `fetch` etc. There is also server-side rendering in Vue, which makes it somewhat a view engine for node server: ssr.vuejs.org

Comment: You can find https://nuxtjs.org/ as it or as a middleware nice to use for this case. It has some templates to get started with.